# A way to throw an exception and log it

Tags: c#, .net

I have a lot of this in my code:

```
if (labelType == null)
{
    var errorMessage = "Invalid Label Type Id Look up: " + labelTypeId;
    log.Error(errorMessage);
    throw new ApplicationException(errorMessage);
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
FailureActions.Fail("Invalid Label Type Id Look up: " + labelTypeId);
```

And the `Fail` method would encapsulate the above logic.

But that messes will flow control logic.  The compiler no longer realizes that I am throwing an exception.

**Is there another way to condense this code? (that works with the flow analysis of the compiler)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make your logger method return the exception.

You can then write

```
throw FailureActions.Fail("Invalid Label Type Id Look up: " + labelTypeId);
```

Note that if you forget to add `throw` at the callsite (especially if your method returns void), your exception will be silently discarded.
To help with that, you can make your method also `throw` the exception (but still return it so that the callsite can write `throw`).

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks!